# Map lines into a columnlist in R

Tags: r

I have a chr vector like this:

```
t<-c("lucas","2","3","luciano","1","5","jack","1","luciana","2","3","4","5")
```

Lucas,2,3 would be the same client. Luciano,1,5 would be a different one and so on.

I created two vectors, where i define the limits of each client.

```
start<-c(1,4,7,9)
end<-c(3,6,8,13)
```

I need to map them in a column list. So I have one column for each client. And if i would click it, i would open each clients matrix.

In this case, I imagine one columnlist, with three rows. If i would click Lucas's list i would have

> Lucas 2 3

And Luciana

> Luciana  2 3 4 5

There is any way i can do this with map?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "column list" and "clicking" on lists. I'm also confused why you expect three rows when you seem to have 4 observations. What is the format of the desired output for this sample input? Can you include that so possible answers can be tested and verified?

Comment: My best guess is you want `map(seq_along(start), ~t[start[.]:end[.]])`. But also pretty confused about "clicking on" things and "columnlist". This gives a regular `list` as the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about doing it with `map` but `mapply` seems to work pretty well:

```r
t<-c("lucas","2","3","luciano","1","5","jack","1","luciana","2","3","4","5")

start<-c(1,4,7,9)
end<-c(3,6,8,13)

output <- mapply(start, end, FUN = function(start_i, end_i){
  t[start_i:end_i]
})
```

[image: Output]

Or you could get fancy with the list names and do something like:

```r
output <- mapply(start, end, FUN = function(start_i, end_i){
  t[(start_i+1):end_i]
})
names(output) <- t[start]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` as shown by @Gregor Thomas but in your case I think `map2` is more suitable which is similar to base R option `mapply` shown by @Dubukay.

I am too confused about click and open matrix part in your question but perhaps you meant to set the name of the list.

```
list_vec <- purrr::map2(start, end, ~t[.x:.y])
names(list_vec) <- t[start] 
list_vec

#$lucas
#[1] "lucas" "2"     "3"    

#$luciano
#[1] "luciano" "1"       "5"      

#$jack
#[1] "jack" "1"   

#$luciana
#[1] "luciana" "2"       "3"       "4"       "5"
```

So now you can use `list_vec$lucas` to get all of `lucas`' elements.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Ronak. I think it might help me in a different problem.